# How do I ensure that a CoreOS cloud-config service is able to download files?

Tags: systemd, wget, coreos, cloud-config

I am defining a one-shot service in my CoreOS cloud-config, but it is failing due to not being able to download files from Google Cloud Storage (via wget):

> Apr 13 11:09:56 staging-node-ys9y.c.experimentalberlin.internal sh[1132]: Connecting to storage.googleapis.com|74.125.133.128|:443... failed: Connection timed out.

How should I ensure that the service be able to download files from the Internet?

### My cloud-config

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  units:
    - name: bootstrap.service
      command: start
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Bootstrap instance
        After=network-online.target
        Requires=network-online.target

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        RemainAfterExit=true
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /tmp/kubernetes-staging
        ExecStart=cd /tmp/kubernetes-staging
        ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "cd /tmp/kubernetes-staging && wget https://storage.googleapis.com/experimentalberlin/staging.tar.gz && tar xf staging.tar.gz"
        ExecStart=/tmp/kubernetes-staging/worker/bootstrap.sh

        [Install]
        WantedBy=local.target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a multi-step tactic to troubleshooting this.  Pardon the extra info and over explanation, everyone here at CoreOS has to deal with this from me. ;)

First and foremost you want to make sure that the URL you are trying to download from can be retrieved from inside the cluster.  Presently, I don't see any reason why this should *not* be the case as I was able to wget it (as an aside, it's generally better to not put private key material in a publicly accessible tarball.  In this case while still not *optimal* it may be better to include those assets either in the `user-data` or at the very least protect the tarball with [symmetric encryption](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Operational-GPG-Commands.html).)

As cloud-init runs after the network is online, this should be sufficient (the meta-data service resides at `http://169.254.169.254` and thus the cloud-config cannot be retrieved until after the network is online.)  This means that the likely culprits are down to transient network issues, or other details.

When I attempt to run through this I get the following error:

```
core@rbtest ~ $ journalctl -u bootstrap.service
-- Logs begin at Wed 2016-04-13 17:31:35 UTC, end at Wed 2016-04-13 17:33:09 UTC. --
Apr 13 17:31:47 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/bootstrap.service:10] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: cd /tmp/kubernetes-staging
Apr 13 17:31:47 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal systemd[1]: Starting Bootstrap instance...
Apr 13 17:31:47 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal sh[1074]: --2016-04-13 17:31:47--  https://storage.googleapis.com/experimentalberlin/staging.tar.gz
Apr 13 17:31:47 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal sh[1074]: Resolving storage.googleapis.com... 209.85.200.128, 2607:f8b0:4001:c08::80
Apr 13 17:31:47 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal sh[1074]: Connecting to storage.googleapis.com|209.85.200.128|:443... connected.
Apr 13 17:31:48 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal sh[1074]: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Apr 13 17:31:48 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal sh[1074]: Length: 4722 (4.6K) [application/x-tar]
Apr 13 17:31:48 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal sh[1074]: Saving to: 'staging.tar.gz'
Apr 13 17:31:48 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal sh[1074]: 0K ....                                                  100% 47.4M=0s
Apr 13 17:31:48 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal sh[1074]: 2016-04-13 17:31:48 (47.4 MB/s) - 'staging.tar.gz' saved [4722/4722]
Apr 13 17:31:48 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal systemd[1]: bootstrap.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 13 17:31:48 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Bootstrap instance.
Apr 13 17:31:48 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal systemd[1]: bootstrap.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 13 17:31:48 rbtest.c.coreos-support.internal systemd[1]: bootstrap.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The clue here is the line:

```
    bootstrap.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
```

This message is telling you that there was a problem running the script itself.  Digging in this makes complete sense as when I look at the top of that shell script there is no [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) telling systemd *how* to run the executable (in this case it's all [Bourne Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)/[Bourne-Again Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) compatible commands, so the shebang should likely be either `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`.)  Adding a shebang should fix this issue.

Some other minor nits:

- when using `wget` specify the download location :

  ```
  wget -O /tmp/kubernetes-staging/staging.tar.gz https://storage.googleapis.com/experimentalberlin/staging.tar.gz
  ```
- when expanding your tarball, you can output it to a specific location with `-C`:

  ```
  tar  xf /tmp/kubernetes-staging/staging.tar.gz  -C /tmp/kubernetes-staging/
  ```

This allows you to separate those into their relevant `ExecStart=` options, which provides additional logging.

- As most of these commands are pre-amble to the execution of the actual `bootstrap.sh` script, I would change all of the `ExecStart=` options (with the exception of the last) to `ExecStartPre=`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the private data in there! :) It's just for test purposes now anyway, so it doesn't matter much, but it shouldn't be like that!

Comment: I had to add a cheeky `ExecStartPre` to wait for the network to be available before I could get past wget failing: `ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'until ping -c1 google.com; do sleep 1; done;'`. I guess you might have a point about other stuff being `ExecStartPre` stuff as well.

Comment: Interesting, my boot on GCE worked on the first go-round.  I'm curious as to why this isn't being successfully handled by `network-online.target`.

Comment: You and me both! /curious

Comment: I confirmed that it keeps failing even over my home network (was at a coworking space earlier), so it's reproducible.

Comment: I found out what was happening... I assigned an external IP only upon SSH-ing into nodes, and before having an external IP nodes couldn't connect to the Internet...